# Check all bytes of a __m128i for a match of a single byte using SSE/AVX/AVX2

Tags: sse, simd, avx, avx2

I'm looking for efficient ways to compute the following function:

Input: `__m128i data, uint8_t in`;

Output: boolean indicating if any byte in `data` is `in`.

I'm essentially using them to implement a space/time efficient stack for bytes with capacity 8. My most efficient solution is to first compute a `__m128i tmp` with all bytes as `in`. Then check if any bytes in `tmp\xor data` is a zero byte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, AVX2 has efficient byte-broadcast.  SSSE3 `pshufb` with an all-zero mask is just as cheap, but you have to create the shuffle-control vector.  AVX512BW/F even has single-instruction [`vpbroadcastb/w/d/q  x/y/zmm, r32`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpbroadcastb:vpbroadcastw:vpbroadcastd:vpbroadcastq).  (With optional masking, so you can zero some or merge with an existing vector if you want, e.g. insert at a position using a single-bit mask.)

Fortunately, compilers know how to do this when implementing `_mm_set1_epi8` so we can leave it to the compiler.

Then it just boils down to the usual `pcmpeqb`/`pmovmskb` to get an integer which will have a `1` bit for matching elements, which you can branch on.

```
// 0 for not found, non-zero for found.  (Bit position tells you where).
unsigned contains(__m128i data, uint8_t needle) {
    __m128i k = _mm_set1_epi8(needle);
    __m128i cmp = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(data, k);  // vector mask
    return _mm_movemask_epi8(cmp);          // integer bitmask 
}
```

As you'd expect, all compilers make this use this asm ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAOgCYAOAJyCALAFYADPwDswucNIArLqVbNaoZAFJeAIR27SAZ1QBXYsg4ByHQGY8tZK1NYA1FtsBhPAFsfDgmIHbgQPbC0JAEE7BycXTHcvIwJ8ehCwiOiogNc0emYHIwgAfWKfTgE8V3RmAmZSV1MA/mKCV1pMTHR2AEp3aX0o12HXUvLK1wBrRIARUb9io0wCTmLMAAc8fggOrt6PQciR0bKK/irkH3XZ%2BZ9iy/XMAEc1ze2auobJnoPhgHo/q4AG6YZBEYiuHzMIyTTLHYjLcy0W5lVAgqEw15bCAPH62XTHQmuAGuAKYYCYCEAI0IGOmmS00hmmSsPVUICsYispFoHIk3NQHM8BgMrhM5ks7l4tk43IIfNZbMmIFsIj4ADZ1SJeNJ%2BLx1fx1ZxbPx2VYRNzeVZ%2BaRBVZuUYQBJSPLrazSHBYDBEChUFc8OwyBQcX7NoGQMB%2BLZSFQAwRKY6IFSFaQabRmMQAJ4c2WkNB%2BTD0ADytFY2bdpCwUI07BT%2BARYLwIMdFcwAA9QaZ4znuWTWCnWHgqcQM5nPBhrLnAr4e2yaPQmGwODwBMJxFJZPIFGoNCgRXpVEPHZA2ah1gQ8HQWwBaIu2YbXgDqbFYD6hFlCthmMMzakmmAdMwLGXNl%2B05S0UztNtDWvLVXGAZBkFcfhuHvCBcEIEgpRlBpx39QNsM4PphT0Aw5QVHolRAfVuE4OjBDEThBHVWwZREfhOHVM0LVIHwQEkHlII5B0nRdCiPW9CAkHzMNKXISgZIDSkUB3YBpAkZ1Y1YeNiETZMKzTUcezzP0fELAgSzLOtMGrYBawretQQvZsU3bTtuysXM%2BwHIcRyzccsGM6c%2BM89150YFhaxXIRREkGQt23dRNH3QxBypY8IFPc9L1oG87wfZ9WFfa932QT9v0mX9mH/QCJRAs0uUEisoJguCnCS1xpG4CRutcdD8HBQjcNDJSITsXhiJS8i3Uo0gEEwZgsGIShQI5Hi%2BIEq0bTtETnVdflZuVVVaM41jxB1SQZTEM1bAg5rhLEmaJPgT0fUUwN5JDfDlLwRCmM4GM4wTSh9JtQys2M/MzOLUtyxtKskvs%2BG8AbZzMBbG03OQLtJ17ehMDAm00r8scJyCoIQtlOc6AipcuD4GL13ihLVCSvdSIPNKMqyi8rw5W971cJ8XzfDMyo8Cqqpq4wgMsLhVvAprto5aD1VgkRSUQ1wmO62i%2Bowwa7AB1w8NksbpVsSaOd0aaDqomVuCNaRpWkLUxBYsQRGkbjuQ250toFB7HT28TXqk31vqDBSRvDIFkHWdZiiBJjik44o2y1QHtOBpMU3B8tcyh8zLLh7kEZraxkdRpt0dcjtsY8rz8cJ7lidHALcZdCnZxjGnFyihm1zizct1Z3dtGtw90vgHmcry3ghbFpBIgANQADQX68AHEgVq4D5Yau7lasDONZ8Iw4%2BBHXOP1gasKN4bI%2BwkQrf0PRbcVOaFqWlafd4/j/ZCXtMYUS%2B1P5HR4E7F2bsPZexukfQOwCwGzTArwBBtoHrILZCCXSOUQAiCAA))

```
contains(long long __vector(2), unsigned char):
    vmovd   xmm1, edi
    vpbroadcastb    xmm1, xmm1
    vpcmpeqb        xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
    vpmovmskb       eax, xmm0
    ret
```

Except MSVC, which wastes an instruction on `movsx  eax, dl` first.  (Windows x64 passes the 2nd arg in RDX, vs. x86-64 System V passing the first *integer* arg in RDI.)

---

Without AVX2, you'll get something like this with SSSE3 or above

```
# gcc8.3 -O3 -march=nehalem
contains(long long __vector(2), unsigned char):
    movd    xmm1, edi

    pxor    xmm2, xmm2
    pshufb  xmm1, xmm2         # _mm_shuffle_epi8(needle, _mm_setzero_si128())

    pcmpeqb xmm0, xmm1
    pmovmskb        eax, xmm0
    ret
```

Or with just SSE2 (baseline for x86-64):

```
contains(long long __vector(2), unsigned char):
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-12], edi
    movd    xmm1, DWORD PTR [rsp-12]    # gcc's tune=generic strategy is still store/reload  /facepalm
    punpcklbw       xmm1, xmm1          # duplicate to low 2 bytes
    punpcklwd       xmm1, xmm1          # duplciate to low 4 bytes
    pshufd  xmm1, xmm1, 0               # broadcast

    pcmpeqb xmm1, xmm0
    pmovmskb        eax, xmm1
    ret
```

---

Related:

- [How to compare two vectors using SIMD and get a single boolean result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875128/how-to-compare-two-vectors-using-simd-and-get-a-single-boolean-result) and many duplicates
- [How can I count the occurrence of a byte in array using SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552656/how-can-i-count-the-occurrence-of-a-byte-in-array-using-simd)
- [SIMD/SSE: How to check that all vector elements are non-zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155897/simd-sse-how-to-check-that-all-vector-elements-are-non-zero#comment62475316_34156477) (`pxor`+`ptest`+`jcc` = 4 uops vs. `pcmpeqb`+`pmovmskb` + macro-fused `test/jcc` = 3 uops.)
- [The indices of non-zero bytes of an SSE/AVX register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681201/the-indices-of-non-zero-bytes-of-an-sse-avx-register) (finding the match positions)
- [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541129/how-to-count-character-occurrences-using-simd) (like memchr but counting matches instead of finding the first, using AVX2.  With efficient accumulation of the counts, and efficient horizontal sums.)

Comment: Nice! Didn't know there is a byte-broadcast instruction!